# OperationFailure error when using projection with a query for an array field through find()

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to use the find() method in order to query for all documents in my collection that have an array field named 'branches' and then project using '$' so that only the first element of the array is included. However, it says that the "positional operator (branches.$) requires corresponding field in query specifier" (full message shown below).

For some background information, I am using PyMongo 3.8.0 and have connected to our database through SSL, with no errors in any other queries I have tried thus far.

```py
for doc in db.employees.find({'branches': {'$exists': 'true'}},
                             {'branches.$': 1}):
    pprint(doc)
```

I expected to be able to see all documents that have a 'branches' array field, showing only the '_id' field and the first element of 'branches', but I see this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/imehta/IdeaProjects/MongoDB/intro.py", line 51, in <module>
    {'branches.$': 1}):
  File "C:\Users\imehta\.conda\envs\MongoDB\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1225, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "C:\Users\imehta\.conda\envs\MongoDB\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1162, in _refresh
    self.__send_message(g)
  File "C:\Users\imehta\.conda\envs\MongoDB\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1010, in __send_message
    helpers._check_command_response(first)
  File "C:\Users\imehta\.conda\envs\MongoDB\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 155, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: positional operator (branches.$) requires corresponding field in query specifier

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: its working on my end. can you please share the exact document structure that is stored in your collection? also what is the mongodb version? that can also be an issue.